# WYSIWYG with CK editor Profiles

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using WYSIWYG with CK editor library. The problem is its showing blank toolbar by default on WYSIWYG editor on node add/edit page. To make the buttons appear on the WYSIWYG toolbar I always have to goto admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/full_html/edit

and have to select which buttons to appear on the WYSIWYG editor toolbar.

Is there a way we can select all check boxes at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Firebug or any other browser that has a console. You need to go to edit page of the WYSIWYG profile and on this page, open Firebug or your browser's web developer tool. And in the console enter this line and run:

```
jQuery('#edit-buttons input.form-checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

This will set all the checkboxes under 'Edit buttons' section and you can save your setings.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can do that out of the box.

If you repeatedly need this functionality, you can write a small custom module that will add a checkbox on that page using `hook_form_alter()` and then through javascript enable all those checkboxes.